# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\ 0}\left(\frac{\cot(x)(1-\cos(3x)^{2})}{x^{2} + 5x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I tried find a this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0}\left(\frac{\cot(x)(1-\cos(3x)^{2})}{x^{2} + 5x}\right)$$

I came to this:

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0}\frac{\frac{\cos(1-\cos(3x)^{2})}{\sin(1-\cos(3x)^{2})}}{(x^{2} + 5x)} = \frac{\frac{\cos(1)}{1-\cos(3x)^{2}}}{(x^{2} + 5x)} =  \lim_{x\to\ 0}\frac{1}{\sin(3x)^{2}(x^{2} + 5x)} = \infty $$

But book says that the correct answer is $\frac{9}{5}$. How should I solve it?

Comment: How did you come to this?

Comment: @VIVID i added details

Comment: Are you sure about $5x^2$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah its just 5x, edited

Comment: are you sure that $1-\cos(3x)^2$ is the argument of $\cot$?

Comment: You can't just substitute $0$ for $x$ in one of the subexpressions and not the others.  I edited your post to improve the formatting.  Please check that I didn't accidentally change the meaning.  I'm wondering if the original numerator shouldn't be $\cot x\left(1-\cos^23x\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Originally the numerator was "${ctgx(1-cos(3x)^{2})}$," i.e. $\cot(x)\cdot (1-\cos^2(3x))$. Then the limit is indeed $9/5$, as can be seen by invoking $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\sin(k\theta)/\theta=k$ for constant $k$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cot(x)\sin^2(3x)}{x^2+5x}
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\tan(x)}\cdot \frac{\sin^2(3x)}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{x+5}=1\cdot 9\cdot \frac{1}{5}
$$